# the nearest td value

Tags: jquery

I have a table:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>some1</td>
          ......
        <td>some2</td>
        <th>count</th>
        <th>EditCount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>some1</td>
          ......
        <td>some2</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td><input type='text' value='1'/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>some1</td>
          ......
        <td>some2</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td><input type='text' value='3'/></td>
   </tr>
```

How to get td value in left side from input in each row, for example when user clicked on this input?

Comment: Do you mean the `td` containing 25 & 35? Or something else?

Comment: Then see @ManseUK's answer. Should be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note from "left side" i took this to mean the first `td` ie the leftmost one)

Try this :

```
$('input[type=text]' ).change(function() {
  var firsttd = $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr'));
});
```

Uses the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method in jQuery (this could be `focus` or `blur` etc). Uses the selector `td:first` to get the first `td` and sets the context to the current objects (`input') parent`tr`

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/3tkyW/)

### Update

To get the previous `td` (ie with values `25` or `35` use :

```
$('input[type=text]' ).change(function() {
  var prevtd = $(this).parent('td').prev('td');
});
```

This gets the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) `td` and then the [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) `td`

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/3tkyW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Or.. something like this

```
$('table input').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('border','1px solid #f00');
});
```

Although I would personalized the selected with a class or something so it's not that common

Comment: This will set the `td` that contains the `input` to have a border !

Comment: Sure, it was just an example to access TD, and show it's actually this TD, since TD's in the provided example do not have any values to change

Answer (score 0):

Add a class let suppose 'value'  to all left side tds then  and add another class on inputs
call this function

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
$('.button_class').click(function(){
        var myvalue = $(this).parent().children().attr(value);
});
```

this will automaticall select first children or you can use this too

```
var myvalue = $(this).parent().eq(0).attr(value);
```

Comment: Your first script has an extra bracket `}` and will also produce an error saying `value is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Are you comfortable using jQuery? If so, then you can use the prev() function in jQuery to do get the immediately preceding sibling (the previous td in this case)

Read this : http://api.jquery.com/prev/